# Is SSL still secure if SSL Settings in IIS is set to ignore or accept only?

Tags: web-services, security, ssl, https, xamarin.android

Is `SSL` still secure if `SSL` Settings in `IIS` is set to ignore or accept only?

I have setup my `https` and I can access it in my browser even it is set to require SSL and `clientCredentialType` = Certificate but I am having a problem in my mobile development as I take a web reference with require SSL settings. I don't know what to do since it says http status 403: forbidden.
So is it still secure if I only set the ssl settings to accept or ignore and my web config's clientCredentialType is set to none

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
```

because this is the only way (for now) that I can access my web service

[image]

Answer (score -2):

When you say **Require SSL** it means that the browser needs to have the certificate (client certificate). Ensure that client certificate is installed on your mobile

Comment: Sorry for misleading but my real problem is not in mobile itself because it already occurred during the development while requesting for web reference. In short as I think, if I can make vs to know the client certificate then I can download the web service. Otherwise I can't deploy it on mobile since error occurs during development.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that, it means that the server should require the client to be speaking SSL to the server. The server will also send a CertificateRequest message during the SSL handshake, and the three radio buttons determine what the server does next, and they are respectively Ignore, which means don't care if the client didn't send a certificate; Accept, which means accept and check it if sent, and Require, which means terminate the connection if the client didn't send a certificate.